# Linking JSF libraries from JBoss in Maven

Tags: eclipse, maven, jsf, jakarta-ee, jboss

I have a very simple web project in Eclipse that uses JSF and runs with a JBoss 4.2.3. I have 'Mavenized' the project and a pom.xml is generated. The pom.xml is empty with no dependencies, but I can install this maven project and I see my web page when I run the JBoss from eclipse. All fine till here.

Now I need to extend the logic of the java code and I need to add a new artifact generated from another project, and here is where my problem starts. When I add a dependency to this new artifact and I try the make a 'install' I am getting this error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile
> (default-compile) on project MyTest: Compilation failure: Compilation
> failure:
>
> [ERROR]
> /home/daniel/workspace/valais/voba-switch/src/ch/steria/scada/sw/web/controller/SwitchController.java:[7,24]
> package javax.faces.model does not exist
>
> [ERROR]
> /home/daniel/workspace/valais/voba-switch/src/ch/steria/scada/sw/web/controller/SwitchController.java:[45,13]
> cannot find symbol
>
> [ERROR] symbol  : class SelectItem

I see the libraries missing are in the jboss-web.deployer directory of the JBoss. How can I link this libraries in the pom.xml or how can I get the right ones from the jboss maven repository for my jboss vesion?

Thanks,
Dani.

Comment: Your combination of question and answer is unclear. Partly because it is unclear what was initially in the pom and how the answer solves this. Please make both better!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to set the artifacts from JBoss as 'provided'.